# Convert device time to unix timestamp based on device timezone

Tags: javascript, react-native, date, timestamp, timezone

I am able to get the correct date with time according to the device timezone. But when I convert that time to timestamp, I am getting timestamp of local timezone (checked in [epochconverter](https://www.epochconverter.com/)), not the device based timezoned timestamp.

I have tried below code to get timestamp from date:

```
1. new Date().valueOf()

2. var tzt = moment
          .unix(Date.now())
          .tz(DeviceInfo.getTimezone())
          .toDate()
          .getTime()

3. +new Date(Moment(new Date().toISOString()))

4. Moment(new Date().toISOString()).unix()

5. Date.now()

6. var forDate = Moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm a');
   var forDateTime = Moment(forDate, "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm a").toDate().getTime();
```

For e.g. I have set America/Chicago timezone in device. I get date as Fri Feb 21 2020 23:59:12 GMT-0600 (CST) which is correct for chicago but timestamp as 1582351152244 which is local timestamp of India.
My expected result is:  1582329552000

Comment: Just a suggestion:  It's usually safer to do everything in UTC and only convert to some local value for display purposes.

Comment: It's not for display purpose. I just need the correct timestamp according to timezone.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to misunderstand the value returned by the *valueOf* method of a Date instance: it's a millisecond offset from 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (the ECMAScript epoch, which is common to a number of computer languages and systems such as Java and UNIX). It does not have a timezone, nor should you infer that it has one. *valueOf* is equivalent to the *getTime* method.

ECMAScript Date objects are just a time value, an offset from the ECMAScript epoch, plus some basic methods to get and set date and time values either based on local (host offset) or UTC values and rules. They don't have a timezone and are inherently UTC. Timezone information is obtained from the host system (or whatever other API an implementation may implement that satisfies ECMA-262).

> I get date as Fri Feb 21 2020 23:59:12 GMT-0600 (CST) which is correct for chicago[sic] but timestamp as 1582351152244 which is local timestamp of India

1582351152244 is **not** a "timestamp of India", it's a millisecond offset from the ECMAScript epoch and represents 2020-02-22T05:59:12.244Z, 2020-02-21T23:59:12GMT-06:00 (Chicago) and 2020-02-22T11:29:12.244GMT+05:30 (India Standard Time). It represents all those timestamps at the same time, as they all represent the same instant in time in different timezones.

When you adjust the value by the host timezone offset, the result is a time value that represents a different moment in time. The code in your answer is equivalent to:

```js
// OP code
var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
var localOffset = (-1) * new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
var stamp = Math.round(new Date(currentTime + localOffset).getTime());
console.log(stamp)

// Concise equivalent, might be 1 ms different sometimes
let d = new Date();
let stamp2 = d.getTime() - d.getTimezoneOffset() * 6e4;
console.log(stamp2);
```

Without knowing why you feel the need to adjust the time value or the outcome you're trying to achieve, it's impossible to suggest a better way of going about it.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the answer to my question. I used below code to convert timestamp according to device timezone.

```
var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

var localOffset = (-1) * new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;

var stamp = Math.round(new Date(currentTime + localOffset).getTime());
```